# Meaning of TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG in SpamAssassin

Tags: email, spamassassin

I am trying to find out what is the meaning of the flag `TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG` in SpamAssassin.

The provided description for it says:

> To: lacks brackets and HTML and one image

As far as I understand it means the mail message is in HTML format and contains only one image, but what does "To: lacks brackets" mean?

Comment: +1 Documentation for TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG is still missing: https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG

Comment: @malisokan this link no longer works & I couldn't find a working one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also ran into this problem and digged in the [source code of spamassassin](https://github.com/apache/spamassassin/blob/47a9e7d8a4271cbe11df8eeacf6a50628f1f6caf/rulesrc/sandbox/jhardin/20_tbird_image_spam.cf) and found this:

```
meta       __TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG  __TO_NO_ARROWS_R && !__TO_UNDISCLOSED && HTML_MESSAGE && __ONE_IMG
meta       TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG    __TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG && !__FM_TO_ALL_NUMS && !__FROM_FULL_NAME && !__HAS_THREAD_INDEX && !__DKIM_EXISTS && !__HAS_SENDER && !__THREADED && !__LONGLINE 
describe   TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG    To: lacks brackets and HTML and one image
score      TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG    2.000   # limit
tflags     TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG    publish
```

So, a single image in a email and a missing name in the `to` field seems to trigger this. To be more concrete, this happens, when:

- The recipient does not contain `<` and `>` (`__TO_NO_ARROWS_R`)
- The recipient is undisclosed (`__TO_UNDISCLOSED`)
- The email contains html (`HTML_MESSAGE`)
- The email contains exactly one image (`__ONE_IMG`)
- The sender (from) does **not** only contain numbers (`__FM_TO_ALL_NUMS`)
- The recipient (to) does **not** contain a name (eg. `foo@bar.de <foo bar>`) (`__FROM_FULL_NAME`)
- Dont know what this is for, the [comment in the sourcecode](https://github.com/apache/spamassassin/blob/47a9e7d8a4271cbe11df8eeacf6a50628f1f6caf/rulesrc/sandbox/kb/70_misc.cf) itself says `# Explain later. ;)` (`__HAS_THREAD_INDEX`)
- No [DKIM signature exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) (`__DKIM_EXISTS`)
- No `Sender`-header is given (`__HAS_SENDER`)
- Is not part of an conversation (?) (`__THREADED`)
- Line length does not exceed 998 characters regarding to [RFC 5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) (`__LONGLINE`)

Answer (score 4):

"To: lacks brakets" means that the `To:` header value has no ending `>`

`To: <destination@domain.com>` Doesn't trigger the rule
`To: destination@domain.com` Does trigger the rule

You can get more information about Internet Message Format [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)

Comment: Why are brakets important, if you have got an image in your HTML mail? I do not get it!

Comment: In my case `destination@domain.com <destination@domain.com>` has a score of `0` with no errors, but `destination@domain.com` triggers the error. Weird.